# Uma dúvida simples

Tags: android

Olá pessoal acabei de baixar uma apostila de android e estou com duvida sobre um exercicio irei postar as imagem de como está na apostila e como eu fiz e gostaria que alguém me explica-se porque não está reconhecendo os comandos seeMessageButton e OnClickListener:

**apostila:**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**como está no android studio_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name_label"
        />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/see_message_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/see_message"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_message_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_message"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        />



</LinearLayout>
```

**como está no android studio_layout_ codigo main:**

```
package com.example.pc_vicl.myapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText nameEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
        seeMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.see_message_button);
        final TextView showMessageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_message_text);

        seeMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                String name=nameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
                showMessageText.setText(getString(R.string.hello_message, name));
                showMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        });

    }
}
```

**como está no android studio_layout_strings:**

```
<resources>
    <string name="name_label">Nome:</string>
    <string name="see_message">Ver mensagem</string>
    <string name="app_name">Ola Mundo </string>
    <string name="hello_message">Olá, %1$!</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Adicione os códigos diretamente aqui, editando sua pergunta, senão fica dificil reproduzir seu código para achar uma solução. E explique melhor o problema que está enfrentando.

Comment: obrigado pela dica

Comment: Que erro está dando? Não ficou muito claro na pergunta. E explique o que você está tentando fazer, só pelos códigos não dá para saber.

Comment: não recohece o comando seeMessageButton  nen o OnClickListener

Comment: Provavelmente porque é `final`. Declare o `EditText` e o `TextView` como parametros da classe.

Comment: desculpe minha ignorância mas como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Esquece, execute novamente, não tem erro aparente no código.

Answer (score 1):

Está tentando utilizar `OnClickListener` sem fazer o `import`, terá que adicionar o `import` da seguinte forma:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Já na linha 14 do seu código faltou especificar o tipo no momento em que declara `seeMessageButton` veja:

```
Button seeMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.see_message_button);
```

Espero ter ajudado